# Indicate in which consecutive ages the number of people of the following age is most higher than the number of people of the previous age

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

`Name= letters[1:5]`

`Amount <- c(1, 4, 9, 2, 0)`

`df <- data.frame(Name, Amount)`

The problem is I have to print a pair of consecutive **Name** that the **Amount** of the name after is the most larger than the name previous. For example, in my data frame **df**:

(a,b) is 1&4 -> 4-1=3

(b,c) is 4&9 -> 9-4=5 (Correct answer)

(c,d) is 9&2 -> 9-2=-7

(d,e) is 2&0 -> 2-0=2

So the answer would be : **b c**

I have tried something like `as.data.frame(table(df))` and `count()` to extract the desired value but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't understand the rule for `correct answer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `diff` and `which.max`.

```
with(df, Name[which.max(diff(Amount)) + 0:1])
#> [1] "b" "c"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a column with the differences you could do something like,

`df <- mutate(df, Diff=Amount-lag(Amount)) # get a new column with the difference`

```
Name    Amount  Diff
<chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
a   1   NA
b   4   3
c   9   5
d   2   -7
e   0   -2
```